# Php Syntax Unexpected Sytax Error

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

I want to write like this in php. How can i express samely into php?

```
$test = '{"longUrl": "http://www.yahoo.com"}';
```

Thanks.

Comment: i want to use as string in code. it doest not contain json or array etc.. so, it gives an string error with like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$test = array("longUrl" => "http://www.yahoo.com");

>echo $test['longUrl']
http://www.yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write actual PHP code to make a new object (assuming your example is JSON), there's no literal/shortcut syntax in PHP for that; you have to make a new `stdClass` object and set its variables manually:

```
$test = new stdClass;
$test->longUrl = "http://www.yahoo.com";
```

If you are comfortable writing JSON inside a string, as you are doing in your example, simply feed that into [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and you have yourself a `stdClass` object:

```
$test = json_decode('{"longUrl": "http://www.yahoo.com"}');
```